# Probability of a particle travelling a distance before decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I want to find the probability of a particle travelling a distance greater than 0.5mm before it decays. I know the mean lifetime of the particle at rest and it's momentum components.

I know how to calculate the average distance of the particle before decay but not how to calculate the probability of it travelling a specific distance. Do I have to manipulate the equation:

$$ P(t) = e^{-t/(\gamma \tau)}, $$

where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor and $\tau$ is the mean lifetime of the particle at rest?

Any hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What does $P(t)$ represent?

Comment: The probability of the particle existing after time t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you also have the rest mass of the particle. So, you can calculate its $v\gamma$ from $|p|$, and thence using the trigonometric relationship between $v/c$ and $\gamma$ (if $v/c=\sin\theta$ then $\gamma=\sec\theta$) you can determine $v$ and $\gamma$ separately.

And then you can work out how much time (in its rest frame) it takes to cover the given distance. And from there you should be able to figure out the probability of it lasting for that amount of time before decaying.